# Removing a subdomain from Google

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website with a lot of subdomains pointing to their own branded directory.

Google have indexed all of the subdomains and I do not want them shown on Google search.

I have added a robots.txt file and added each directory to it and also added a .htaccess file to every directory with the following code in:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
```

Why is it Google still index the directories even though I have requested them to remove every other page (which they have done) but left all of the directories?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Google is that they re-index every 3-4 weeks, sometimes it can be a longer period. So it will not be something that you will see take an immediate effect.

You will have to be patient I'm afraid! They will be removed, Google are just very slow with these sort of things.

There is an option for On-Demand removal from Google, but I believe it is for deleted / inappropriate pages.. but you can find info about that [here.](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/indexing#on-demand-removal)

Answer (score 1):

> I have added a robots.txt file and added each directory

But you must also add a `robots.txt` file in each subdomain directory. Because Google is not going to look for a connection between domain and subdomains. And your subdomain directly displays the folder contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily remove the domains via the Url Removal Tool that google provides. https://search.google.com/search-console/removals

You will however need to own the domain to be able to remove these urls. Also the removal is temporary, and you need to use one of the methods -

X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" in Header

Block access to site using proxy server or password.

documentation on the tool - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846?hl=en